# ros2: ros2 pkg create for python package problem

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I created ROS2 packages using

```
ros2 pkg create package_name
```

Whenever, I do that, it creates a C++ package with CMakeList.txt.

I tried to use the option `--build-type`, but it only suggests `cmake` and `ament_cmake` as build type. There is no option for ament_python.

I want to create a python package, but could not see any means to do that. Should I write setup.py and package.xml manually or there is a command to do it?

Also, I understood that Python code should be in a Python package, and C++ code should be a C++ package and could be merged, where as in ROS1, Python and C++ can at the same package. Is my understanding correct?

PS. I am using latest bouncy version in Ubuntu Bionic.

Thanks
Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298327/ros2:-ros2-pkg-create-for-python-package-problem/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you are referring to `ros2 pkg create`? This command has been added in https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/pull/42 and atm only supports generating CMake projects. If you want to create a Python package you need to do that by hand for now (using existing Python ROS packages as templates).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on 2018-07-23**:
noted. thanks!
that's what I did.

**Comment by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on 2018-07-24**:
I opened a ticket for `ament_python` support. https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/125
I labeled it as a "good first issue", because I think the infrastructure should allow to extend it for python rather easily. So if you feel motivated, you may want to open a PR for supporting it. :)

**Comment by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on 2018-07-25**:
that will be great add this functionality.